# Store an instance in Express js session

Tags: node.js, session, express, instance

I'm using the expressjs session, and I have a instance need to store:

```
function a(){this.name="";}
var ins = new a();
req.session['user'] = ins;
```

and when I get res.session['user'] next time, the object is not instanceof a, and it cannot access any prototype methods in a, 
how can i store the ref of the object in session, looks the session will convert it to json object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store instances like that in JSON unless:

- You provide your own custom serializer (implementing a `toJSON()` function in your class/object)
- You also identify your serialized object and instantiate a new instance in the [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Example.3A_Using_the_reviver_parameter) function you pass to JSON.parse().

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is create an instances/session map which you can identify via the `session.id`, I blogged about this here:

https://tomblanchard.co.uk/storing-instances-in-express-sessions/