# nodejs Appending date object to user in session

Tags: node.js, date, session, attributes

I have set up nodejs with express, sessions, mongoose etc. Login and navigation works all fine, now I just want to append additional information to the user, specifically a date object.

Here is how I attempted to do that:

```
var user = req.body.user;
if(user) {
    if(!user.viewdate)
        user.viewdate = new Date();
}
```

Note - I removed a lot of my code to highlight the problem at hand.

Now for some reason when I do that, Nodejs tells me that `user.viewdate` is actually a string and not a Date object, which means that I can't access any of the date functions.

```
console.log(typeof(user.viewdate) + ", " + user.viewdate);
// prints: string, 2017-05-23T13:37:57.672Z

user.viewdate.getDate();
// TypeError: user.viewdate.getDate is not a function
```

I have actually solved the problem by converting the string to a date object, editing it, and then converting it to a string again.

```
var date = new Date(user.viewdate);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
user.viewdate = date;
```

But all this converting seems tedious and unnecessary when I could just access the actual date.

Can someone tell me, if it's possible to save a Date attribute to a user in a session?

Comment: try Date.parse(string)

Comment: Like I said, converting string to Date / Date to string is not a problem. I'm just wondering why I can't save the date object directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797119/store-an-instance-in-express-js-session