# store puppeteer page into session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, puppeteer

i want to store puppeteer page into session to use in another middleware in express

here is my code in first middleware:

```
  (async () => {

    let solve;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
    await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

    await page.click('button.imeiInquiry');

    const images = await page.$eval(('.captcha-image[src]'),node => node.src);

    

    res.send({
        type: 'img',
        url: images,
    });


    req.session.page = page;


})();
```

and here is the code in 2nd middleware:

```
(async () => {
    const page = await req.session.page;
    res.send(await req.session.page.title);
    await page.type('#CaptchaInputText', req.body.capchaNumber);
    await page.type('#ImeiNumber', req.body.imei);
    await page.click('.swal2-confirm')
})
```

but 2nd middleware doesnt work

Comment: `page` objects are too complex for persistent session data -- if you just want the page to last for the request, add it to [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals), otherwise, keep an identifier to look up the in-memory `page` object in `.session` and store the `pages` in a map. Can you provide more details about your use case? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store an instance in Express js session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797119/store-an-instance-in-express-js-session)